# Quick NOTETAKING with Android

Tags: notes

I often resort to pen and paper for quick notes like telephone-numbers, because I feel using my phone will take to long.

Are there any apps for android that will let me be just as quick (freehand), without beeing "just" a drawing application?

Need to somehow sync into cloud or web.

Ideally it should be possible to quickly open the mick and attach the input
(Like evernote)

Answer (score 1):

There are [plenty of note taking apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=note&c=apps) on the Play Store :

- [**Evernote**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote), [its Android Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote.widget) and [all the official Evernote apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Evernote%20Corp.) (like [Skitch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote.skitch)) are available on the Play Store.
- If you do not want to use Evernote you have got the same thing with [**Catch.com**](http://catch.com). There are its [Catch Notes app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.threebanana.notes) and [all the other](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Catch.com) on the Play Store.
- You can use the official [**Microsoft OneNote**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.onenote) app for Android if you are a Microsoft OneNote user.
- If you do not want online sync, you can use [**Note Everything**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.softxperience.android.noteeverything). It is a free app but there is also a [Pro Add-on](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.softxperience.android.noteeverythingpro) (€2.99) with more features.
- You can also try [**Scribb.it**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lioncode.notepad) which is more of a multipurpose note taking app. Its free but you can get a [Premium Key](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lion.notes.premiumkey) (€0.85) to enhance your experience.
- Google released [**Google Keep**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep), its own note taking app too.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible, and when I'm feeling lazy, I just use my camera.

Otherwise, I use ProDo (it's a task manager). I have a widget on my homescreen, and I just touch it when I want to make a quick and short "note" (or task). *Notes or Tasks, it doesn't matter*. When I'm done with them, I delete the "note", or move the data to other apps like Evernote or Contacts, if necessary.

Comment: Really? A downvote?